# Using Generics with EF classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF6 with Code First and have a few tables with virtually the same schema. I would like to be able to perform queries on these tables and return the results to a common object (class) rather than creating a new one for each.

So for example, EF won't allow:

```
public class Product1 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Product1> Products1 { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product1> Products2 { get; set; }
```

So I have to define a second POCO:

```
public class Product1 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Product2 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Product1> Products1 { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product2> Products2 { get; set; }
```

At least I would like to be able to treat results from these POCOs the same so that I can plug results into another class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public <Product1 or Product2> Product { get; set; }
}
```

Be able to store the result from either db table in the same object:

```
SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass();

someclass.Product = _context.Products1.Where(p => p.id == 1).First();
```

or

```
someclass.Product = _context.Products2.Where(p => p.id == 1).First();


int thisId = someclass.Product.id;
```

How do I make `someclass.Product` generic so that it will accept either Product1 or Product2?

Comment: Would letting both classes implement a common interface help? Like: `public interface IProduct { int id { get; set; } string name { get; set; } }`? -- And then let the `Product` property in `SomeClass` be of type `IProduct`.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make the classes inherit from an interface and then use that interface in a generic type constraint.

```
public interface IProduct 
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}

public class Product1 : IProduct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Product2 : IProduct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could define SomeClass as follows:

```
public class SomeClass<TProduct> where TProduct : IProduct 
{
    public TProduct Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This way you basically get two different `SomeClass` classes and you can't put a `Product2` in a `SomeClass<Product1>`. If that is what OP wants.